# Typescript import global node_module fail

Tags: node.js, typescript

I installed a global `node_module`, import error. It said Cannot find module 'puppeteer'. But if I required it, it successfully.

```
npm install -g puppeteer
```

I've set the `NODE_PATH`, I can require global node_modules

javascript

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';  //Cannot find module 'puppeteer'
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');  //Success
```

I expect import success

Comment: I fixed. The solution is typescript.json .   {"compilerOptions":{"baseUrl": ".","paths":{
              "your module name":["your global node_module path"]
          }}}